# How to set the container name used for --link option with Docker

Tags: docker

I'm a looking for a method to specify manually the host name used when we are linking container together (`--link`). The default host name used with --link is the uuid of the container.

I don't speak about the alias set on the run command but the effective host name use inside the container.

---

**Context**

I have some third party backend to run which doesn't validate correctly docker hosts names starting by number (Eg. 239f5de9e420):

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI$MalformedURIException: Host is not a well formed address!
 at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.setHost(JaxmURI.java:971)
 at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.JaxmURI.initializeAuthority(JaxmURI.java:646)
```

When I looked to the implementation of the lib [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/util/JaxmURI.java#JaxmURI.isWellFormedAddress%28java.lang.String%29), I saw the validation except  hosts starting with number match IP format. Since it's a java lib, other may face the same issue.

For now, we are restarting the container until his uuid start with a letter. Patching manually the lib is not in the context of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the flag `-h` of the command `docker run` ?

```
   -h, --hostname=""
      Container host name
```

Comment: Dead simple. According the first tests looks good. Damn I read the online docs where there is just a small reference (not really well place btw) I missed... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I helped. Feel free to perform a PR for their doc ;)